# Building grpc fails

Tags: java, build, grpc

i try to buld grpc

my java

> java -version
>   openjdk version "1.8.0_144"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.5.1) (suse-10.15.2-x86_64)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

start build :

> ./gradlew build

*** Skipping the build of codegen and compilation of proto files because skipCodegen=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/susi/grpc-java/build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'grpc'.

  > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/ltgt/gradle/errorprone/ErrorPronePlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

BUILD FAILED in 0s

what get wrong ?

Comment: What version of gRPC are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 or later (Java 8 preferred) is required to build. You can still use the produced binaries with Java 6 and 7.

This is documented in the second line of [COMPILING.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.12.0/COMPILING.md).